# ORA-00972 identifier is too long

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to store more than 3500 characters in my table. so i used nvarchar2(3500) datatype for my Data field . but when i try to insert the data i get the error "ORA-00972: identifier is too long". Could anybody help me on this please.

Comment: Use single quotes to delimit strings not double quotes.

Comment: I think it has to do with your insert statement. Could you paste it here?

Comment: have you considered clob/blob ... ?

Comment: Identifier too long means a column name or alias is too long (limit is 30 characters), nothing to do with your data.

Comment: @Colin'tHart - But if you do `CREATE TABLE T (D nvarchar2(1000)); INSERT INTO T VALUES("This is a string longer than 30 characters")` you would see this error.

Comment: That's not a string, that's an identifier. Strings in Oracle use single quotes. So yes, if you are trying to use double quotes to delimit strings, use single quotes, like @MartinSmith comments.

Comment: None of the column name length is exceeding 30 characters. But my data contains simplified Chinese language Text.Is this creating any trouble there?

Comment: @santhosha - Post your code.

Comment: is your text in single quotes? CREATE TABLE T (D nvarchar2(1000)); INSERT INTO T VALUES('This is a string longer than 30 characters')

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE T (D nvarchar2(1000)); 

INSERT INTO T (D) 
VALUES('This is a string longer than 30 characters')
```

Oracle has a restriction on Objectnames longer than 30 characters.